# how to replace " from my string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My string is "apple"
I want it as apple only
how to replace those double quotes from my NSstring.

eg:

```
NSstring *str=[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@""" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 6):

```
NSString *str = @"\"apple\"";
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"after--%@",str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Escape double quotes character in the old string:

```
NSString *str2 = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want any special character like ", &, ' to be as a part of a string, then use a backslash () escape character before that special character.

More about [escape character](http://www.digitalamit.com/article/regular_expression/2.phtml)

```
NSstring *str=[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY using following :

NSString *myString = [oldString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *s = @"\"a\""; // s = "a"
    NSString *str=[s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"s: %@",str); //s: a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *test = @"\"Apple\"";
NSLog(@"%@", test); 
NSCharacterSet *doNotWantTheseCharacters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\""];
test = [[test componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWantTheseCharacters] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
NSLog(@"%@", test);
```

Above code can be used to replace an character from string.